# Zeppelin authentication with Jdbc realm

Tags: apache-zeppelin, shiro

I have been trying to set up zeppelin with authentication with Shiro JDBC realm. After all my attempts, I have not been able to get it working. The basic authentication works but with JDBC realm it fails.

The zeppelin server was created following the doc: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/quickstart/kubernetes.html

The POD is working.

I enabled the Shiro by extending the docker image. My Dockerfile:

```
ARG ZEPPELIN_IMAGE=apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
FROM ${ZEPPELIN_IMAGE}
#https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/dockerfile


WORKDIR ${Z_HOME}

ADD /zeppelin/shiro.ini ${Z_HOME}/conf/

ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.4/mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar ${Z_HOME}/lib/
ENV CLASSPATH=${Z_HOME}/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar:${CLASSPATH}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/tini", "--" ]
WORKDIR ${Z_HOME}
CMD ["bin/zeppelin.sh"]
```

My shiro.ini taken from https://gist.github.com/adamjshook/6c42b03fdb09b60cd519174d0aec1af5

```
[main]
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.databaseName = zeppelin
ds.user = zeppelin
ds.password = zeppelin
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealmCredentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $jdbcRealmCredentialsMatcher
ps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $ps
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $pm
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login
[urls]/** = authc
```

Now, when I deploy the zeppelin server, I get:

```
rg.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class [com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource] for object named 'ds'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified class name correctly.
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:327)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$InstantiationStatement.doExecute(ReflectionBuilder.java:961)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$Statement.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:921)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:799)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:278)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:181)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:107)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:150)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)


Caused by: org.apache.shiro.util.UnknownClassException: Unable to load class named [com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted.  Class could not be found.
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:152)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:320)
    ... 40 more
```

Not sure why it is failing even I have defined the jar file on classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with jar was not having the right permissions. Got it fixed with below Dockerfile

```
ARG ZEPPELIN_IMAGE=apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
FROM ${ZEPPELIN_IMAGE}
#https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/dockerfile


WORKDIR ${Z_HOME}

USER root
ADD /zeppelin/shiro.ini ${Z_HOME}/conf/

ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.4/mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar ${Z_HOME}/lib/
ENV CLASSPATH=${Z_HOME}/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar:${CLASSPATH}

RUN chmod 777 ${Z_HOME}/lib/mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar

USER 1000


ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/tini", "--" ]
WORKDIR ${Z_HOME}
CMD ["bin/zeppelin.sh"]
```